# MS Office 2013 Addon Click Once, change install directory

Tags: c#, .net, clickonce, office-addins

I use Click Once to deploy a Office 2013 Addon, written in .NET 4.5.1
This works fine and the Addon is installed here;

C:\Users[User]\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0....

But now i need to change the destination path of the installation to:
C:\Users[user]\AppData\Roaming... some thing

How can I do that, or is that not possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try copying the installation to the folder you want it in then update the click once setup.exe to look there.

From the command line navigate to the installer folder then:

```
 setup.exe /url="C:\Users[user]\AppData\Roaming\"
```

If you want to change where the installer installs to every time this is not possible see:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/5c7d00c2-2473-4fd5-b815-30066383eb47/change-installation-folder-for-a-click-once-app?forum=winformssetup